# READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in app bundle explorer

Tags: android, google-play-console

my issue is related to permission. I do have app published to google store and Google reported that my app is using `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. I am not able to detect this permission in my app using Manifest merger tool. I also went through all `AndroidManifest.xml` in my project included libs added as dependencies but I can not see any `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission added to project.

I uploaded .aab file to App bundle explorer available in Google play developer page and they report permission issue onward.

Does anyone have idea what or where I should check my code?

I also try to remove this permission using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove"/>
```

but it does not work for me. They still report that my app is using this permission.

Comment: If you have WRITE you have READ too.

Comment: But what is the problem? Your app will not be refused.

Comment: Where does it report this permission ? Can you share a screenshot of the part that shows this permission? Also, can you share a screenshot (even if redacted) of the merged manifest?

Comment: @blackapps, thats the point, I was not aware of this. My manifest contains WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Unlucko, some types of app can not have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - Google says.

Comment: @Pierre https://play.google.com/console/about/app-bundle-explorer/

Comment: Make sure to check the merged manifest in Android Studio to find where that permission comes from: https://developer.android.com/build/manage-manifests#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts

Comment: @Master Did you fix it ? I have the same thing

Comment: @EdharKhimich Unlucko, there is not one simple way. If I have WRITE it mean I have READ too. Google said that my app can not have READ permission so I had to remove permission and found workaround to download files using DownloadManager without permissions.

Comment: @MasterDisaster Thank you for your reply. Yea, I did the same last week. Will see what Google will say about it hehe